# how to trigger the update of data in standard oracle apps table without using trigger?

Tags: oracle-apps

I want to trigger whenever the scheduled shipment date of sales order changed in oracle apps,but it is not recommended to write to trigger on standard oracle apps table , what is the alternative to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the scheduled shipment date of sales order is changed manually in the form, then you have use Form Personalization with the WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD and provide the below condition

```
TO_DATE(:LINE.schedule_ship_date) <> (SELECT TO_DATE(schedule_ship_date)
FROM oe_order_lines_all
WHERE line_id   = :LINE.LINE_ID)
```

In actions, Type:'Builtin'
Builtin Type: 'Execute a Procedure'
Argument:'Provide the procedure name'